# How can I install me gemfile, its giving errors?

Tags: travis-ci, gemfile

This is my gem file:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'fastlane'
gem 'cocoapods'
gem ‘CFPropertyList' gem ‘slather'

plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fastlane', 'Pluginfile')
eval_gemfile(plugins_path) if File.exist?(plugins_path)
```

And this is the error message im getting:

```
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Undefined local variable or method `‘CFPropertyList' for Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /Users/jordyhuijgens/Desktop/project folder/BwLidar/Gemfile:5
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  gem 'cocoapods'
 >  gem ‘CFPropertyList' gem ‘slather'
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to install Travis CI for my IOS app.

Answer (score 0):

Enter line each dependency

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'fastlane'
gem 'cocoapods'
gem 'CFPropertyList' 
gem 'slather'

plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fastlane', 'Pluginfile')
eval_gemfile(plugins_path) if File.exist?(plugins_path)
```